# In-Place DC Upgrade from Server 2003R2 Standard to 2008 Enterprise

Tags: windows-server-2008

We have a Domain controller in server 2008 Enterprise and Additional DC in server 2003 R2. Now I need to upgrade Additional Domain controller to Server 2008 Enterprise and raise the  domain functional level to 2008. The DC is running with Active Directory, DNS and DHCP. The server is installed in VMware ESXi 4.0. Please guide me to carry out the upgrade. Also I want to know about the possible risk of in-place upgrade, if any.

Comment: If these are virtual I would be tempted to build a 3rd domain controller in 2008, make sure everything is working correctly and then shutdown the 2003 R2 one, change IP/DNS etc.

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct upgrade path between Server 2003R2 (x32) and Server 2008 (R2)(x64) . Microsoft documented the upgrade procedure very well however, and in your case, a simple `dcpromo` (demotion) backup of the `DHCP` settings and after that set up a fresh 2008 box, install `AD`/`DNS`/`DHCP`services and put a backup of the `DHCP` configuration back on to it should be the way to go.

[This is the place to start for documentation on the process](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd365353%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

Comment: I am planning to upgrade from 2003R2 (x32) to 2008 Ent (x32).

Comment: @YadhuTony  Well, don't, but either way, you can't directly do an OS upgrade on a Domain controller.

Comment: @YadhuTony As Hopeless said, don't do that... Active Directory is the single most important service in your network, keep its installation extremely clean, do not try any sort of upgrade. Build a clean VM/box, dcpromo, etc, demote the old Controller once the new one is working and slowly phase out it's services.

Comment: @ChrisS : Thank you for your reply. As you said, to be on safe side, I am planning to do a fresh installation.

Comment: @ChrisS : I just tried to do the upgrade and it became a success. But as you said it is a very risky process and not recommended too.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do the upgrade and it became a success. Here are the steps that i have taken before upgrade.

1.Server hardware was checked for compatibility with the Microsoft Assessment & Planning Toolkit
2.Software compatibility was tested.
3.All non-Microsoft applications were disabled with msconfig and DFS service was disabled.
4.Hardware has been checked for faults including tests with chkdsk,diskpart, netdiag, dcdiag, and defragmenting the disks.
5.Forest and domain has been prepared using adprep /forestprep & adprep /domainprep. Even though it became a success I won't recommend the in-place upgrade because of its potential risk.